# How to add to a store of a combobox in extjs 4?

Tags: extjs4

I have tried the following from various examples and none of them work:

```
 folderCombo.store.add({text: 'All', value: 'ALL'});
 folderCombo.getStore.add({text: 'All', value: 'ALL'});
 folderCombo.getStore().add(new grid.store.recordType({text: 'All', value: 'ALL'}));
 folderCombo.store().add(new grid.store.recordType({text: 'All', value: 'ALL'}));
folderCombo.getStore().add(folderCombo.getStore().recordType({text: 'All', value: 'ALL'}));
```

Where folderCombo is my combobox. If I console.log folderCombo.store it shows the current store but never the store with the extra data item I try to add above.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
folderCombo.getStore().add({text: 'All', value: 'ALL'});
```

or:

```
folderCombo.getStore().loadData({text: 'All', value: 'ALL'},true);
```

Comment: maybe that: folderCombo.getStore().loadData([[text: 'All', value: 'ALL']],true);

Comment: Can you send your important rows of code? I will try to figure it.